# Set custom compiler in eclipse (omp4j)

Tags: java, eclipse, openmp

So I am trying to use omp4j with the eclipse IDE. The problem is, that omp4j needs to replace the javac command to work (see http://www.omp4j.org/download). And I don't know how I can accomplish that in eclipse other than renaming the `omp4j.jar` to `javac.jar` and replacing my JDKs `javac.jar` and that seems like a wrong solution.

Comment: Eclipse doesn't use javac - it has its own internal compiler that can't be changed.

Comment: That's quite unfortunate.

Comment: [_`omp4j` is source-level preprocessor. It means it takes a Java source code and returns Java source code as well. The statements that should run in parallel are marked with special comment._](http://www.omp4j.org/tutorial) To execute the omp4j preprocessor on save you can use an [Ant script as project builder](https://help.eclipse.org/2018-09/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-92_project_builders.htm) with two folders, one for the source code to edit (not on the Java build path) and one for the generated preprocessed code (on the Java build path).

Comment: Alternatively, the omp4j preprocessor can also only be executed within an Ant, Maven, Gradle, etc. build, since the code that has not yet been preprocessed is also valid Java code.

Comment: @howlger not quite, as omp4j has the fields `OMP4J_THREAD_NUM` and `OMP4J_NUM_THREADS` which of course aren't known before processing.

Comment: If you choose the alternative way, in the not yet preprocessed source code these fields can be faked via a static import to avoid invalid Java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`omp4j` is a **preprocessor**. If `omp4j` is called without `--no-compile`, the preprocessed Java source code will be automatically compiled via `javac`, so `omp4j` can be used as a replacement for javac.

**Eclipse has its own** incremental **Java compiler which can not be replaced**. This means, in Eclipse `omp4j` has to be used with the argument `--no-compile` as preprocessor only. The processor can be executed

- in an Ant, Maven, Gradle, etc. build script or
- via an [Ant build script as project builder](https://help.eclipse.org/2018-09/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-92_project_builders.htm) on save.

To have the full Java support for the sources before preprocessing, the `OMP4J_THREAD_NUM` and `OMP4J_NUM_THREADS` constants can be faked via a static import statement with the `*` wildcard and a JAR that exists in two different versions, one with these face constants for the sources to edit and one with other constants for the generated sources which are not intended to be edited.

Probably it will be best to start with a Java project for each, before and after preprocessing.